# NullReferenceException Fire Ball

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

I'm working on this game [breakout-game](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-a-breakout-game)

And i'm trying to make the ball fire and collide with the wall bouncing, to do that I did what he said, I added a script and put this code:

```
public class BallMove : MonoBehaviour {


private Rigidbody rb;
public float ballVelocity = 800f;

private bool isMove; 
// Use this for initialization
void awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && isMove == false) {
        transform.parent = null;
        isMove = true;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        rb.AddForce (new Vector3(ballVelocity,ballVelocity,0));
    }
}
```

}

I understand every line of this code, but when I try to play this, I got a nullReferenceException ,I can run the game but when I press the key I'm getting a error,someone know why? and what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Awake()`, not `awake()`. In your case, you are using a "customized" function, and not the "official" one used by the Unity engine.

So, the engine cannot start that function by itself, and `rb` stills null when used in the `Update()`.

Example:

```
void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 2seconds, this is the answer, given that the gameobject also has a rigidbody attached

Comment: @ParadoxForge: nice catch! Yes, it is a typical mistake by people that try to learn Unity. Case sensitivity is often ignored :-)